# How to know when process gets killed in unix

Tags: unix, ubuntu

I am working on an Spark project which has an executable which starts the process in background , now I need to know when the process gets killed through Bash.The only solution I got is to continuously check its PID existence through grep in loop if exist or not , Is there any other possible solution that do it without looping around .
I also tried handling the exit codes ,but the exit code is 0 if process runs and only changes when it gets killed which need to be checked continuously

Comment: What programming language are you using? Please [edit] your question to include the relevant source code from your executable, so that we have a starting point for improving it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right, the situation is this:

Your executable does somewhere `fork` and run another logic in another process, and you want the main process to get notify whether the forked process is still running.

In order to answer I'll make sure we both are familiar with the same terminology:

The main process (when you run your executable) is called the **parent process**.

The process that the **parent process** is starting, is called the **child process**.

Now when a **child process** dies a signal `SIGCHLD` is sent to the **parent process**, Normally `SIGCHLD` is mapped to `SIG_DFL` which is actually `SIG_IGN` for `SIGCHLD`. In human words, it means that the **parent process** does not give a shit if the **child process** dies.

But, If you want to get notify, you may change the behaviour of what happens when `SIGCHLD` is sent. In order to do so you must implement `signal handler` function:

```
void custom_sigchld_handler(int sig)
{
    pid_t p;
    int   status;

    while ((p = waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG)) != -1)
    {
       // If you got here it means p is a dead process. Do your logic here... 
    }
}
```

Then you must declare that you want our `custom_sigchld_handler` to take care of `SIGCHLD` signals:

```
struct sigaction signal_action = {0};   
signal_action.sa_handler = custom_sigchld_handler;
sigaction(SIGCHLD, &signal_action, NULL);
```

Comment: I was thinking that too, but since he's grepping pid's, we can't assume that it's a fork or even a system() call, or for that matter, that it's even in C :)

Answer (score 0):

May need a little more context... if your executable is starting the process, there is surely a way to get or keep a handle on it while executing.

In php, there is proc_open(), in Qt there is the QProcess class, in c/c++, there is popen()

Many languages have this feature, but without more details it's hard to offer a solution.